Can you divide 1000 into two parts such that one part is a multiple of 47 and the other is a multiple of 19?
Can you divide 1000 into two parts such that one part is a multiple of 47 and the other is a multiple of 19?
Note: I teach 8th and 9th graders and they don't know what diophantine equations are.
I wish to help them solve this question without trial and error and without using diophantine equations. In fact, I myself don't know how diophantine equations work. Is there some method to do so?

This question has some close votes stating that it's a math problem. I don't want to take a position in that, but do want to tell you that we have an entire site dedicated to [matheducators.se].

A diophantine equation is just an equation that is restricted to integer solutions.  In your case, calling 1000 = 47X+19Y a diophantine equation is just a very fancy way of saying, "X and Y are integers."

just curious : Suppose someone, maybe OP, improves question to turn the math problem into a math puzzle, perhaps by coming up (I guess that may not be too hard) with a recreational entertaining story mapping 1:1 onto the mathematics. Would there be any chance for question to be reopened? Or is a close always definitive?

@FirstNameLastName Questions can be reopened, especially if they are edited to be on-topic. However, edits should not invalidate pre-existing answers.

@FirstNameLastName , you can vote to reopen the question. With enough reopen votes, the question gets reopened.

One needs sufficient reputation. Apart from that, I believe rephrasing question to become a math puzzle rather than a pure math problem and conform @bobble's hints could encourage people having sufficient reputation to vote for reopen.

ok, relatively prime is a term from 100 level math - but it just means "no common factor other than 1" so esplain it that way. From there you can reason that measuring 47s from one and and 19s from the other there must be at-least one place where the two sequences align.

@Jasen what you are saying requires proof, since it doesn't construct a demonstrably correct answer, and that proof is very much nontrivial.


 Yes

and here's a method that might make sense for your students.

We want 47n + 19m = 1000.
Or 19m = 1000 - 47n
And so 1000 - 47n = 0 mod 19


When n is 0, we have 1000 on the left, which is 12 mod 19. When n is 1, we have 953 which is 3 mod 19. We can keep going a bit...


 


 Your students should notice that the moduli go up by 1 with each "cycle" of 2. They have n = 4 yields 14 modulo 19, so they should try n = 4 + 2 * 5, giving us n = 14 and the desired modulo of 0. They can then solve for m = 18.


Same approach for me, but I had an intermediate step. $1000-47n$ is congruent to $12-9n$, mod $19$. The latter representation simplifies the approach somewhat.

@ApexPolenta That certainly makes the arithmetic easier. I think it depends on the students a bit. Typically, US 8th graders aren't taught modulo arithmetic,  so it may make sense to keep it at a level where "modulus division is like taking the remainder" is good enough.

I don't claim this to be a generic approach, but, for problem at hand it happens to be sufficient.
notice

 50 - 3 = 47 and 20 - 1 = 19 (i.e. add deltas 3 and 1 respectively)

There are not too many ways to write

 50 * 20 = 1000

as a (natural number coefficient) linear combination of

 50 and 20



 1000 = 0  + 1000 =  0 * 50 + 50 * 20 [50 = 3 *  0 + 1 * 50]
 1000 = 100 + 900 =  2 * 50 + 45 * 20 [51 = 3 *  2 + 1 * 45]
 1000 = 200 + 800 =  4 * 50 + 40 * 20 [52 = 3 *  4 + 1 * 40]
 1000 = 300 + 700 =  6 * 50 + 35 * 20 [53 = 3 *  6 + 1 * 35]
 1000 = 400 + 600 =  8 * 50 + 30 * 20 [54 = 3 *  8 + 1 * 30]
 1000 = 500 + 500 = 10 * 50 + 25 * 20 [55 = 3 * 10 + 1 * 25]
 1000 = 600 + 400 = 12 * 50 + 20 * 20 [56 = 3 * 12 + 1 * 20]
 1000 = 700 + 300 = 14 * 50 + 15 * 20 [57 = 3 * 14 + 1 * 15]
 1000 = 800 + 200 = 16 * 50 + 10 * 20 [58 = 3 * 16 + 1 * 10]
 1000 = 900 + 100 = 18 * 50 +  5 * 20 [59 = 3 * 18 + 1 *  5]
 1000 = 1000  + 0 = 20 * 50 +  0 * 20 [60 = 3 * 20 + 1 *  0]



 in above table I write sum of the linear coefficients multiplied by their deltas (3 and 1) inside brackets


 notice some regularities in coefficients and sums, probably not a coincidence

now

 57 is the only sum that itself can be written as linear combination of 47 and 19

namely

 57 = 3 * 19

therefore solution is

 1000 = 14 * 47 + 18 * 19 where 18 = 15 + 3


IMHO the "right" general approach to this kind of problem is the

 Chinese Remainder Theorem

You are looking for numbers $X+Y = 1000$ such that (1) $X \equiv 0 \mod 47$ and (2) $Y \equiv 0 \mod 19$ which implies (3) $X \equiv 1000 \mod 19$ and (4) $Y \equiv 1000 \mod 47$.
The CRT ensures that there are numbers $0 < X,Y < 47\times 19$ satisfying (1-4).
The CRT itself says nothing about how to compute these solutions but there is a standard tool for that, namely, the

 Extended Euclidean Algorithm which is simply a version of the Euclidean algorithm that keeps track of more things.

Using the EEA we find $47\times 17 \equiv 1 \mod 19$ and $19 \times 5 \equiv 1 \mod 47$. The solutions ($\mod 47\times 19$) are therefore $47x17x1000 \equiv 658 \mod 47\times 19$ and $19 \times 5 \times 1000 \equiv 342 \mod 47\times 19$. It remains to verify that $X=658,Y=342$ is indeed a solution.

Isn't an issue that 47×19=893 which lower than 1000? Can we use CRT in such case? I thought that to use CRT, the coprimes product must be at least N (1000).

@Krzysztof It works for arbitrary $N$. In fact, given the solutions for all $0 \leqslant N < 893$ (which you believe to exist) we can easily produce solutions for arbitrary $N$: just solve the equations for $N \bmod 893$ (here: $107$) and the solution will work for $N$ as well.

@Adayah But some of the solutions might involve negative numbers, right?  And then they wouldn't solve the OP's question as posed.

@AriBrodsky you can choose 0<X,Y<=893. The sum can then only be 107 or 1000. If it is 107 you replace either X or Y with itself + 893.

Agreed CRT and EEA are the best "right" tools here. I am not familiar with 8th and 9th graders courses. What age are we talking about? Do their mathematics courses cover EEA and CRT?

@FirstNameLastName In the US, at least, neither would ever be covered. The CRT in particular is something that is quite valuable to teach to those students participating in math olympiads and other competitions, so if this course is for a very gifted students, this would be a really nice lesson. Even so, I would reserve it for 10th/11th graders.

@kagami ... thx and sorry to ask (I am from EU) : what age typically are +/- are 8 9 10 11 graders?

8th graders are typically 13 when school starts in September. The US significantly under-emphasizes number theory (by which I mean, ignores it completely in most curricula), so it may be different elsewhere.

Kind of a "hacky" solution (but it can be made generic as well)

 Notice that there are easy-to-find adjacent multiples of 47 and 19, namely $47\times2=94$ and $19\times5=95$. That means that $19\times5+47\times(-2)=1$ (in general, these coefficients (5 and -2) can be found using extended Euclidean algorithm, as stated in Albert Lang's answer), or, multiplying everything by 1000, $19\times5000+47\times(-2000)=1000$. Now all we need is to make the coefficient -2000 positive. We try to "replace some of the 19s with 47s", i.e. write $19\times(5000-47x)+47\times(19x-2000)=1000$ and find an integer $x$ such that both coefficients are positive.
 Now it's trivial: $$\frac{2000}{19}\leqslant x\leqslant\frac{5000}{47}\ \text{or approximately}\ 105.3\leqslant x\leqslant106.3.$$ The only solution is picking $x=106$, giving $19\times18+47\times14=342+658=1000$.


This is a really nice and intuitive solution and probably well suited for the target audience.

fwiw: Exactly same way one can reason: 193-471=10 so starting 19300-47100=1000 via x=6 one finds solution

This was my thought process when I was 13/14 years old and I saw a question like this for the first time:
The numbers we can get by combining (positive or negative) multiples of 19 and 47 are the same as the combinations of 19 and 47-19=28.  This is simply because (47-19)+19=47, so we can recover 47 from 19 and 47-19. That is we do not lose anything by replacing 47 with the smaller and easier number 28.
But why stop there?  We can take away 19 again from 28 and get 9.  By the same logic as before, we can replace the 28 with 9, so our new numbers are 9 and 19.  The numbers you can get by taking combinations of these are the same as the numbers you get by taking combinations of 47 and 19. Note we could do this all in one step by dividing 47 by 19 and taking the remainder 9, to replace 47.
But why stop there?  By the same logic as before, we can take away 2 copies of 9 from 19, to get 1 left over, and replace the 19 with 1.  So the numbers you can get from 19 and 47, are the same as the numbers you can get from 19 and 9, are the same as the numbers you can get from 1 and 9, which are all the multiples of 1.
Writing it out:
$\hspace{26mm} 1000=1000 \times 1$
$\hspace{38mm}=1000\times (19-2\times 9)\qquad{\rm (we\,\, can\,\, get\,\, 1\,\, from \,\,19\,\, and\,\, 9)}$
$\hspace{38mm}=1000\times 19-2000\times 9 $
$\hspace{38mm}=1000\times 19 -2000\times (47-2\times 19)\\\hspace{120mm}{\rm (we\,\, can\,\, get\,\, 9\,\, from \,\,19\,\, and\,\, 47)}$
$\hspace{38mm}=5000\times 19- 2000\times 47.$
Now if I subtract $47k$ from the 5000, and add $19k$ to the -2000, then I will still get 1000, as subtracting $47k\times 19$ and adding $19k\times 47$ does not the change the total:
$$
(5000-47k)\times 19 + (19k-2000)\times 47=1000
$$
This is the exact method (known as the extended Euclidean Algorithm) we teach at university, to solve linear Diophantine equations.  So if the fancy name is off-putting, you can ignore the name.  It is just exactly what a teenager with a bit of common sense would do.
Finally you want the $k$ small enough that $5000-47k$ is non-negative.  5000 divided by 47 is 106 remainder 18, so $k=106$ is the largest you can try.  This is just big enough that $19k-2000=14$ is also positive.  Thus $$18\times 19 +14\times 47=1000.$$

+1 Nice (known) process you came up with as young teenager on your own!.

Though it's nice your answer is easily accessible, you might mention that this is called the Euclidean algorithm.

@aschepler OK added.
